# Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: java

Necesito solucionar el

> Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Si la entrada es 10, debe imprimir *0,0,0.45,0,0,0.65,0,0,0,0.56,0*

Me aparece error cuando la entrada es 9.

```java
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la entrada: ");
        num=leer.nextInt();
        
        String vector="0 2:0.45 5:0.65 9:0.56"; //vector propuesto
        String[] partes=vector.split(" "); //separar por espacios}
       
        String fin=partes[0]; //obtener la clase
        
        //vector vacio
        double[] vec2=new double [num];
        for (int i = 1; i < vec2.length ; i++) {}
        //fin del vector vacio
        
        for (int i = 1 ; i < partes.length; i++) {
            String[] partes2=partes[i].split(":"); //separar indice vector
            fin=fin + "," + partes2[1];//contatenar final
            
            int a=Integer.parseInt(partes2[0]);
            vec2[a]=Double.parseDouble(partes2[1]);

            System.out.println("indice "  +partes2[0]);
            System.out.println("valor " + partes2[1]);
        }
            System.out.println(fin);
        
       }
    }
```

Comment: ten presente que en un array los índices parten de 0,eventualmente vas a obtener el 9 y ese sera el indice de vec2 por ende el unico tamaño que puede tener vec2 es 10(num) cualquier otro ingreso te arrojara ese error

Comment: **Javascript != Java**, y CSS no tiene nada que ver...

Comment: Y no solo con 9 te da error, sino con cualquier número menor a 9. Además... ¿has revisado [estas preguntas](/search?tab=votes&q=index%20out%20of%20bounds%20%5bjava%5d) en el sitio?